# realloc structer that has struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, realloc

iam working on a program that search for name of songs in a text file and add the matching resultat in structure called resulat, i would like to use realloc to increase the memory size of the result strcture each time the function add new song to the resultat of the searching process

```
struct song{ // read name and the year of the song from a file
char* name;
int year;
};

song* allocatesong(){       // function to allocate memory for struct song   
     song* songptr;
     songptr=(song*)malloc(sizeof(struct song));
   
         songptr->name=NULL;
         songptr->year=NULL;

   return songptr;
 }
         

struct result{ // only matching resultat will be added to this structure
song* result_found; // store the found songs
int result_count;   
};


result* allouerResultat(){     
result* resultptr;
resultptr=  (result*) malloc(sizeof(struct result));
resultptr->result_count=0;
resultptr->result_found[resultptr->result_count]= allocatesong();

return resultptr;
}


void add_song_to_result(song* songptr,result* resultptr){   

song* songtemp; // struct to make temporary copy of the song 
songtemp=allocatesong();
songtemp->name=songptr->name;
songtemp->year=songptr->year;

// increase the size of the memory 
resultptr->result_found[resultptr->result_count]=(song*)realloc(resultptr->result_found[resultptr->result_count],((resultptr->result_count)+2)*sizeof(struct song));
resultptr->name[resultptr->result_count+1]->=songtemp->name
resultptr->year[resultptr->result_count+1]->=songptr->year;
resultptr->result_count++;
```

iam having hard time using the realloc and the program is crashing, can you guys please verify if it set correctly

Comment: In C, you cannot use `song` as a type after `struct song` alone; there must be a `typedef` for it. Yet the code you show does that. Are you compiling in C or C++? If you are compiling in C, there is code missing. Edit the question to provide a [mre] with the missing code. If you are compiling in C++, add the C++ tag and delete the C tag.

Comment: Describe the specific problem you are having. Looking at the code, I doubt “the program is crashing.” Attempting to compile the code shown, even after adding `#include <stdlib.h>` and making some corrections, results in error messages from the compiler. The source code does not compile, so there is no program generated, so the program does not crash. Do not say “the program is crashing” when what is actually happening is the compiler is not compiling the program. Say that the program will not compile and show the exact text of the messages you get from the compiler.

Comment: All that said, there are severer places in the code where you mismatch pointers with non-pointers. `songptr->year` is an `int`, so it should be assigned an integer value, like 0, not something intended for pointers, like `NULL`. And `resultptr->result_found[resultptr->resultcount]` is a `song`, not `song *`, so it should be be assigned the `song *` that `allocatesong` returns. You need to fix a number of these errors.

Comment: actually the error are happened when i was writting the code here ,b ut its working with me, i would like to know how can you increase the memory capacite when ever you add a song to result? thank you